# Send modified values from DataWindow to WCF

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, catel

In our WPF application we have Options dialog. Currently by changing each settings there the client sends data to the WCF service. Options dialog is inherited from `DataWindow` and got 3 buttons: OK, Cancel and Apply. Now I am looking for a better solution to cache each modified setting and by clicking on Apply/OK button send the whole batch of modified settings to the WCF. The main issues i faced so far are:

1. Preferences dialog has 3 tabs with different views. Each view has its own view model thus it must be single proxy for all views' changes.
2. With IMementoService I am only able to undo/redo operations but I need to cache the changes and proceed them on demand.

Does Catel provide something useful for that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to create a model which actually represents all the settings. This model can be shared by all 3 tab view models. Then you override the Save method in the view model that belongs to the DataWindow (not the tabs) and you can send the data to WCF there.